# Glympse notification "Smart Device Link" on Android 10

Tags: android, smartdevicelink

since quite a while I get an annoying notification from Glympse about "Smart Device Link". As I am not aware of using that feature, I would like to get rid of the notification.

My search through google brought up a similar issue with accuweather about 3 years ago. Accuweather seems to have solved the issue via an update. But I cannot find any information about this notification related to Glympse.

One option would be to switch off the notification for Glympse. Unfortunately Glympse only has one setting for the notification. So deactivating that would deactivate all Glympse notifications and not just the one about the Smart Device Link.

Reaching out to Glympse for App related issues does not seem possible. On their community page they point to stackoverflow. And thus I am here.

What are my best options to get rid of the "Smart Device Link" notification?

By the way: I am using a Samsung Note 9 runnung Android 10.

Comment: This is super annoying to me as well. Came here looking for an answer!

Answer (score 0):

Same problem. SmartDeviceLink is always looking for a bluetooth connection even when Glympse is not launched, since almost 2 years.

I wrote to Glympse and after 2 months waiting I got an answer :
"You can remove SmartDeviceLink trough Ford"
No more explanation. I don't have a Ford :(

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31755584)